# How to perform Arithmetic operation within JMeter functions

Tags: jmeter

I would like to perform arithmetic functions within JMeter Random functions,like

```
      ${A}-1.${__Random(0,9,)}
```

where A is the counter variable starting from 0-9.

```
      But the above one return as 0-1.4 instead of -1.4.
```

Any help pls. Is it possible to perform addition/subtraction within fn's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you need to replace this line:

```
${A}-1.${__Random(0,9,)}
```

with the one using [__intSum() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__intSum) like:

```
${__intSum(${A},-1,)}.${__Random(0,9,)}
```

Because JMeter doesn't know anything about plus, minus signs, etc. you need to explicitly call this or that [function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html)

Demo:

[image]

More information on JMeter Functions concept: [Apache JMeter Functions - An Introduction](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-functions-introduction)

Comment: For example:

How can I add two functions like: 

**${__javaScript((new Date()).toISOString())} + ${__Random(1000,1500)}**.

Knowing that the first one is changing to String. This is a POST method to save in the database a value of time like '2024-02-08 17:16:58.130'

Comment: For example: comments section is not for asking new questions which are not related to the original by any means. For example you should rather ask a new one. But beforehand for example you can get familiarized with [__timeShift() function](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-timeshift-function) (it's not a part of JMeter bundle, it can be installed using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/) - look for **Custom JMeter Functions**)